# Dispose of File.Open or StreamContent

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

Is the below line for `content.Add` going to leave an object from being disposed correctly?  If so what is the correct way to handle this.

```
 public string UploadGameToWebsite(string filename, string url, string method = null)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new StreamContent(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)), "Game", "Game.txt");
            var task = client.PutAsync(url, content);
            var result = task.Result.ToString();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `await` if you call asynchronous methods??? This code will block even though `PutAsync` is asynchronous. Never mind `File.Open` (which should be enclosed in a `using` statement anyway)

Comment: Another developer did this and I knew it looked bad. I wanted to know exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make your method asynchronous if you are going to be calling an async operation in your method.
2. Dispose your file stream and also the client. In the example below by disposing the `StreamContent` it also disposes the underlying `FileStream`.
3. I prefer a finally block for disposing multiple disposable objects, its also perfectly fine to have nested `using` statements.
4. Not sure why you are returning the `ToString` on the `HttpResponseMessage`, maybe status code would be more useful or see if StatusCode = 200 and return boolean (true/false)?

Code:

```
public async Task<string> UploadGameToWebsiteAsync(string filename, string url, string method = null)
{
    HttpClient client = null;
    StreamContent fileStream = null;
    try
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        fileStream = new StreamContent(System.IO.File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(fileStream, "Game", "Game.txt");
        HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
        return result.ToString();
    }
    finally 
    {
        // c# 6 syntax
        client?.Dispose();
        fileStream?.Dispose(); // StreamContent also disposes the underlying file stream
    }
}
```

Code version #2 using `using` blocks.

```
public async Task<string> UploadGameToWebsiteAsync(string filename, string url, string method = null)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var fileStream = new StreamContent(System.IO.File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(fileStream, "Game", "Game.txt");
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `using (var client = new HttpClient())` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - see point #3. It's pure personal preference.

Comment: Says ConfigureAwait is not an extension method

Comment: @MikeFlynn - Add `using System.Threading.Tasks;` at the top of your code file.

Comment: @MikeFlynn - ConfigureAwait has been removed. Maybe you are not on the latest v. of .net? I am not sure what version it was introduced?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. File.Open returns a stream that should be disposed. The easiest way to do this would be to use a "using" block, like this:

```
 public string UploadGameToWebsite(string filename, string url, string method = null)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), "Game", "Game.txt");
            var task = client.PutAsync(url, content);
            var result = task.Result.ToString();            
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Another issue is the use of `task.Result` instead of `await PutAsync`

Comment: Or use [`WebClient.UploadData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktfa4fek(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `HttpClient.PutAsync` to use its synchronous methods.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain asynchronous methods are *preferable*, especially when performing network IO.